# sdcard not detected after porting

Tags: sd-card, porting, android-sdcard, android-2.3-gingerbread

I have a ported version of Android Gingerbread 2.3.4 running on the Tsunami board by Technexion. In the version of Android, when I insert sdcard its not detected.

I tried porting the device to Froyo and the sdcard is detected in Froyo but not in gingerbread.

Please guide where could the problem be while porting that the sdcard slot is not detected  the sdcard when I insert it? I have the source code but could not really get to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem still not solved but luckily Technexion has released the latest version of ICS which supports SD Card.